# Does mongo query performs better if options is not added when string is numbers only

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am doing a mongo query in our express app with the search value passed by the user.

```
return await Orders.find({
   orderId: {
      $regex: `${search}`,
      $options: "i"
    }
})
```

the `orderId` is of the format `POXXXXXXXXXX` where X represents numbers. Often customer search with only the numeric part of the `orderId`. My question is if I modify my code as below will it make the query faster?

```
const filter = {
   $regex: `${search}`
}
if(isNumeric(search)){
   filter["$options"]= "i"
}

return await Orders.find(filter)
```

I tested these two queries but the results are inconsistent.

Comment: The title and the last code snippet contradict each other. Using of "i" option makes a negligible impact on performance but there is room for optimisation apart from that. Does order always start with "PO" or can it be any characters? Is it always a full number that users submit or can it be only part of it and you want to return all matches?

Comment: always PO will be there. 
Is it always a full number that users submit or can it be only part of it and you want to return all matches? - 90% cases yes

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question - no, conditional case sensitivity in the regexp options will not give you noticeable performance improvements.

Assuming users will search starting from leading numbers you can massively improve search speed by indexing the collection by orderId field.

The search like

```
let numberSearch = search.replace(/^PO/i, "")
return await Orders.find({
   orderId: {
      $regex: `^PO${numberSearch}`,
      $options: "i"
    }
})
```

normalises the input string and uses anchored regexp which can benefit from the index.

Please note the results will be slightly different to the original query. A document with orderId "PO123456" was a match in the OP query but is not in this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Indexing with MongoDB then Your query search speed can improve. If you have not yet applied.

create index with following command,

db.Orders.createIndex({ orderId: 1 },{ background : true , unique : true })

about options ,

background : true

if we want the site live while index creating

unique: true

use it only when the unique field value